# Why can I not use a params variable for the JText translation constant?

Tags: jtext

I'm working on a component, and within the component configuration I have a selector for the admin to choose the date format to use when displaying items.  It seems to me a perfect use-case for component config.

So, within the view I'm retrieving the params from the component config, and assigning the selected date format to a variable.  Passing that variable to JText does nothing.  If I assign the constant to a variable (not from $this->params->get), it works fine also.

For example:

```
// works fine
echo Text::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'); // returns "l, d F Y H:i"

// works fine
$dateformat = 'DATE_FORMAT_LC2';
echo Text::_($dateformat); // returns "l, d F Y H:i"

// doesn't work
$dateformat = $this->params->get('dateformat','DATE_FORMAT_LC2');
echo $dateformat; // returns "DATE_FORMAT_LC2"
echo Text::_($dateformat); // returns "DATE_FORMAT_LC2"
```

I ended up using a switch statement for the whole list of available date formats.  I'm confused as to why the string works but the variable doesn't.

Joomla 3.10.5
PHP 7.4.3

Update:
I found that if I pass the params variable through trim() it works again.  So there's some kind of control character that's piggybacking on the variable from params->get.

Update2 for mickmackusa answer:
The field is defined in JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR./config.xml (component options).  The value is actually different from the innertext, I just haven't come up with better descriptions yet.

```
    <field type="list"
               name="dateformat"
               label="COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATEFORMAT_LABEL"
               class="list_class"
               multiple="false"
               filter="WORD"
               default="DATE_FORMAT_LC2">
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_LC</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC1">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_LCONE</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC2">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_LCTWO</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC3">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_LCTHREE</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC4">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_LCFOUR</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC5">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_LCFIVE</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC6">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_LCSIX</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_JS1">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_JSONE</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATE">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATE</option>
                <option value="DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATETIME">COM_CERTIFIED_CONFIG_DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATETIME</option>
    </field>
```

Update 3:
Submitting the com_config for these component settings, I captured the form payload and found that the value is NOT being submitted with leading spaces.  This is the URL Encoded value in question (notice, no %20 spaces): jform%5Bdateformat%5D: DATE_FORMAT_LC2

Update 4:
This is really fun.  If I change the field type to radio, the problem goes away.  The JSON value does NOT contain spaces and the returned value does NOT need to be filtered through trim() to be used.

Of course, a radio field type is completely unusable with this many options, but it gives a direction to go for troubleshooting.

At this point, I think I should cook up an example component and submit this as a bug to the project.

Comment: Can you please `var_dump($this->params->get('dateformat', 'DATE_FORMAT_LC2');`? This should help to see any invisible characters involved.  Can we also see where `dateformat` is getting sourced from so that we might understand how the invisible bytes are born?

Comment: @mickmackusa - var dump shows 2 spaces leading the variable value.  These aren't present in the input field.  <option value="DATE_FORMAT_LC2">DATE_FORMAT_LC2</option>
// string(17) "  DATE_FORMAT_LC2"

Comment: @mickmackusa - Interesting that I found the double leading space in the database params json value.

Comment: I just want to go on record by saying that it is never necessary to declare a `value` value in an `<option>` tag if it is identical to the option tag's text value.  That said, I don't know if you populated the tag structure of if Joomla was doing that (sometimes software unconditionally declares the `value` attributes).  Next, can you share the source of your data?  Where does your database get this data?  I'd like to follow this error back to the source if possible.  Could you please add all of your discoveries to your question as an [edit]? I prefer to keep comments to a minimum.

Comment: @mickmackusa - long reply - updated the question with the form field source.

Comment: On the rendered webform, if you inspect the element (in your browser's developer tools), are you able to "see" the unwanted leading spaces in the source code?

Comment: No, I pasted that in a previous comment.  Everything is great everywhere, except the database record, and the value returned by params->get.  The problem is occurring somewhere in com_config storing the value.  I even captured the submitted form values and there aren't any spaces there either. (jform%5Bdateformat%5D: DATE_FORMAT_LC2) appended to question.